# MERN Stack, how big of a role can redux play?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, fullscreen, mern

My project involves somewhat of a checklist. Initially, I used Redux to keep track of the state (whether something is checked off or not). Later I implemented a backend node server and a mongo database, and I load data from the database every time I fire up or refresh localhost. Since the checkoffs directly modify the elements in the database, there's not a whole lot Redux is doing that pre-emptive loading isn't already doing.

So my main question is that if the data is fetched from the backend the moment I start everything up, what else can I use Redux for in this case? I know my project might be too small and simple to give out a good answer, but I'd still like to know possibilities if possible.

Comment: If you have multiple components needing the same state then you can use redux. Storing data in the back end does not solve this problem because there may be multiple components trying to load/update at the same time. [Motivation for creating redux can be found here](https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/motivation)

Comment: So rather than pulling data for each component at the start each time I switch components on localhost, I should pull data for all components at the start the application starts up? And store all that data into redux?

Answer (score 0):

No matter, your data is coming form backend but you still need redux for many reasons. Redux is not about just for storing data but it best for performance. Let discuss it with use cases.

Suppose you have main component of **COMPANY** and that is fetching data from API/backend and data cam to **COMPANY** component and same data is required to your **ADMIN** component and you again call network for data, and you know fetching data for each component from backend is very heavy and make your application slow.

So the best solution is to fetch all you data one time and save them in **REDUX STORE** and distribute data over your components.

MAIN ROLE:

1- Easy to manage data and state

2- Optimization and performace improvement with **SELECTORS**

3- Debugging is very easy

4- Easy to track data